# Powershell get output from rabbitmqctl and parse exception

Tags: powershell, error-handling, stdout, stderr

I'm calling rabbitmqctl from Powrshell:

```
$out = (& $path ($arguments -split " ") )
Write-Host $out
```

With a correct path, the output has a success message:

```
Clearing policy "<policyname>" on vhost "<vhost>" ...
```

With an incorrect path, I get an exception:

```
....
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Parameter does not exist
```

The message `Clearing policy` is missing. When stopping the execution, the $_.Exception.Message is empty.

```
try {
   $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
   ...
}
catch {
    Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Is there a way to get both the `Clearing policy` message and the last line `Parameter does not exist`?

Comment: Shouldn't `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` be set _before_ entering the try{}..catch{} block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Redirect the error stream to `stdout` and convert each element to string:

```bsh
$out = (& $path ($arguments -split " ") 2>&1) | % ToString
```

---

When executing external programs (like `rabbitmqctl`), you will not receive any exceptions. You may get output in different streams (mostly `stdout` and `stderr`), and your external program will return an error code, but certainly not an exception, PowerShell could process.

I guess you are using PowerShell ISE. Why? Because in contrast to PowerShell, PowerShell ISE has the strange behaviour to throw an exception if it is forced to print text, that has been received from the error stream of an external program.

You can reproduce it with the following command:

```bsh
where.exe nonExistentExecutable.bla
```

In PowerShell, it will output some text saying, that it could not find a file with that pattern. In PowerShell ISE, you will get a `NativeCommandError` exception, that contains the text from the error stream.

The key point here is, that most executables write to the error stream, if they have to report errors. So does `where.exe` and so does `rabbitmqctl` in your case. You cannot capture the error stream like that:

```bsh
$out = (& $path ($arguments -split " ") )
```

This will only capture the success stream (aka `stdout`). The error stream will be forwarded to the console, and ISE will throw an exception. That's what's happening in your case. To also capture the error stream, redirect it to `stdout`:

```bsh
$out = (& $path ($arguments -split " ") 2>&1)
```

Now, `$out` will definitely capture the result, either the success message or the error message. In case of the error stream, each line will be wrapped by a `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` and even PowerShell (like ISE) would output that in form of an exception. To prevent that, convert every element to string:

```bsh
$out = (& $path ($arguments -split " ") 2>&1) | % ToString
```

This won't have negative impact on success messages and thus can be used in any case.

Comment: I saw you editted my question and ["happy path"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path) is a term, that is why it was in quotes.

Comment: @Bakudan Thx for sharing. Surprisingly,  I've never heard of that before.